# what does shipping to a server means? AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, server, angular-cli

what does shipping to a server means?
Does it means you need to upload on the server the necessary files?

I have the dist folder, package.json, server.js. Do I need to upload it all in my heroku server so that my app will run?

thank you very much. My apologies for being so noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shipping to a server means that you deploy your application on a server where your application will run. This means that all your files which you made which your server will serve are transported to this server.

This server to which you ship your application to is usually a paid service where you pay a company a fee for certain facilities. You can also deploy your own server but this can be a lot of work if you are not familiar with servers.